# How to add a contract editor + export in pdf feature in my react app?

Tags: reactjs, saas, draftjs

I am writing to you today because I need your developer advice.
A friend and I have been developing for several months a project management tool (react + firebase).
The app is well advanced, and we would like to add a contract editing tool. The goal is for the user to have access to an editable template (a window with a text editor) of a contract. Once amended, the contract must be exportable in pdf format.

We are a little confused about how to approach the problem. Following our research we found the frameworks draft.js and pdf2json, but the way to proceed remains unclear for us.

Have any of you ever crafted a similar feature in an application and could you give us some hints?

Any help is welcome, thank you in advance!

Comment: it is not perfectly clear what you want to achieve. Is it a  simple text field or do you want a wysiwyg editor for pdfs in react? in either case maybe take a look at https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: Hello @Marco, thank you for your answer. In fact I would like to show to the user a text editor (in which a contract template is already present, but can be modified), and then add the possibility for the user to convert the editable text into a pdf file